# Power Query: Extract dynamic sheet data for my current file

Tags: powerquery

I have a sheet named "CENTList" which is loaded while activating a VBA macro.
This sheet can then have a dynamic number of rows, with columns extending from A to X, and with headers on first row.

I want to extract this data in Editor Power Query:

I found a way to do it writting specifically the name of the file. The following code is working and you can see on the pic, the "CentList" exists

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("myfilepath\myfilename.xlsm"), null, true),
    DataSheet = Source{[Item="CENTList",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data]
in
    #"DataSheet"
```

[image]

But what I want it is to use the current file, whatever its name.
Then I tried that:

```
    let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="CENTList"]}[Content]{0}[Name]), null, true),
    DataSheet = Source{[Item="CENTList", Kind="Sheet"]}[Data]
in
    #"DataSheet"
```

Doing that, PowerQuery replies me it can't find "CENTList"

Do you know what I should do?

Thanks for replies

Answer (score 0):

Your VBA needs to create a named range

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="abcd", RefersToR1C1:="=CENTList!R7C5:R16C10"
```

or

```
Sub macro4()
Worksheets("CENTList").Activate
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveSheet.Names.Add Name:="abcd", RefersTo:=Selection
End Sub
```

then PowerQuery can read it

```
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="abcd"]}[Content]
```

Comment: Hi @horseyride. Thanks for the answer. It works partially, because it got me only the E7:J16 cells into Power Query, without headers. Do you know why?

Comment: that was a sample. You have to use your own range in place of R7C5:R16C10.  Added another example method of choosing all cells and assigning range

Comment: Did this now work for you? If so, please toggle checkmark to mark as solved and consider upvoting with arrow